# Database connection reuse

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am writing a simple class to make a connection with the database. I want to reuse the class through out my application. Can anyone tell me, how should i do it? I am using JSP and JavaBeans.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Use the connection pool built into your servlet container.

Comment: `I want to reuse the class through`, i am not sure about this statement.or use connection pooling which is best in your case

Comment: Whatever approach you take, make absolutely sure that you only reuse the class instance, not the SQL connection itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create class which implements ServletContextListener:

```
public class YourContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {      
        //This method is called by the container on start up
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {        
    }   

}
```

Then define that listener in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.package.YourContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In the contextInitialized method you can get servlet context by using:

```
ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
```

Add your object into application scope:

```
context.setAttribute("yourObject", yourObject);
```

Get your data source anywhere in your application:

```
YourObject ob = (YourObject) servletContext.getAttribute("yourObject");
```

Comment: hi paulius,                                                                                                                                              I want the code without using the servlet and can you send a sample reusabilty code in java to connect the postgresql database.