# How to configure Connection Pool for Java Web Project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I've been doing a research on connection pool with JDBC api and classes. But still I don't know how to configure a Connection Pool class for a java web project. As you may know, the Connection Pool is a Singleton Class that encapsulates the JDBC apis. But the Connection Class is started once when the web project is deployed on Tomcat Server, I wonder if there's something needed to be done with Web.xml configuration file, to let Tomcat Server load the Connection Pool Class.
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Full documentation is here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html.  Reader's Digest Condensed version: 1) Configure the connection pool in your Tomcat server.xml, 2) Set up a JNDI data source and 3) Make sure all your applications open connections to the JNDI data source (e.g. `DataSource myDs = (DataSource)
  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myDB");`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a many ways of doing this. [JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) is one way - but it is not so "user friendly" in tomcat. The datasource also can be configured in Spring. For e.g.:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

The most simplest way of doing this is to create a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) class, create your datasource and put it into [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) so that the same instance could be retrieved from `ServletContext` in your project.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158810/database-connection-reuse) how to create `ServletContextListener`.

**See also:**

- [How to use JNDI DataSource provided by Tomcat in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring)